# Posição reabertura da tela tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em Python e utilizo o tkinter para criar uma tela conforme abaixo:

```
    import tkinter as tk

    def on_closing():
        cpos = str(root.winfo_rootx()) + '+' + str(root.winfo_rooty())
        # salvo o cpos em arquivo com as coordenadas
        root.destroy()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("teste")
        cpos = '0+0'
        #tratamentos para carregar o arquivo com as coordenadas
        # larg x alt + x coord + y coord
        root.geometry("250x500+"+cpos)
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
        root.mainloop()
```

Consigo salvar, recuperar e utilizar novamente a posição salva. Porém essa posição sempre aparenta uma diferença de alguns pixels, ou seja, nunca consigo fazer com que a tela abra sempre no mesmo lugar. Não sei se o problema é no momento de salvar a posição ou de utilizar novamente no .geometry.
Alguma dica?
Obrigado!!

Comment: Aparenta ter diferença ou tem de fato? Se tem, qual o tamanho da diferença? Essa diferença é constante?

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso desta forma, mas vc pode adaptar para o seu jeito.

```
janela = Tk()
janela.resizable(0, 0)


# dimensoes
largura = 550
altura = 500

# resulução do sistema
larguta_tela = janela.winfo_screenwidth()
altura_tela =  janela.winfo_screenmmheight()

# posicao da tela
posix = larguta_tela/2 - largura/2
posiy = altura_tela/2 - altura/2

# definir a geometry
janela.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (largura,altura,posix,posiy))
```

Comment: Oi Maciel, no seu exemplo o posicionamento da tela sempre será o mesmo. O que eu preciso é retornar a última posição da tela em que o programa estava antes de ser fechado. Como eu disse, guardar e restaurar as informações não é o problema, mas sim no retorno ao .geometry a posição x e y. Sempre fica com alguns pixels de diferença. Obrigado